# Remove PHPWord header image transparency

Tags: phpword

How can I remove transparency form header image using PHPWord Library?
My code is

```
    $phpWord = new PhpWord();

    $phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Calibri');
    $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);

    $sectionStyle = [];

    $section = $phpWord->addSection($sectionStyle);

    $header = $section->addHeader();

    $header->addImage(
        resource_path('assets/images/finlab.png'), [
            'width' => 100,
            'marginTop' => 100,
            'posHorizontal' => 'right',
            'positioning' => 'absolute',
            'align' => 'right'
        ]
    );
```

Now image in header in semitransparent.

Answer (score 0):

When you use resource_path you will get the image URL but to remove the transparency you need to use actual image path instead of image URL.

```
$image=getcwd().'/assets/images/finlab.png'; //or whatever your image path is.
$header->addImage(
        $image, [
            'width' => 100,
            'marginTop' => 100,
            'posHorizontal' => 'right',
            'positioning' => 'absolute',
            'align' => 'right'
        ]
    );
```